# How to reroute requests to local overrides on Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have a browser-based game that uses a couple of sprite sheets that it preloads when it starts up and displays them on a canvas when needed.

Unfortunately those sprites aren't exactly the best, so I want to use my own texture pack of sorts.

I tried to use local overrides on Chrome, but it still loads the default textures when I open it.

Any ideas as to how to make it load the custom textures?

Comment: what is the language used in the game ?

Comment: browser-based - so javascript